# How to plot a rectangular grid on word map?

Tags: python, gridview, geolocation

I've the coordinates(Latitude, Longitude) of the 4 corners of all the 300 grids that I want to plot on the world map. How do I do it in python?

The grids' coordinates are stored in excel/Csv file with the headers : "Box Number", "Top left coordinate", "Top right coordinate", "Bottom left coordinate" and "Bottom right coordinate".

How do I plot it in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top_left_coordinates = (float(values[2]),float(values[1]))
bottom_right_coordinates = (float(values[2])- difference,float(values[3]))     
 folium.Rectangle([top_left_coordinates,bottom_right_coordinates]).add_child(folium.Popup(values[0])).add_to(mapobj)

mapobj.save('map.html')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're searching for, but I've developed a rather flexible way to add bounded gridlines to a map with [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps):

Check the docs for more info: [EOmaps - gridlines](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gridlines)

```py
from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()

for i in range(-180, 180, 20):
    for j in range(-90, 90, 20):
        bounds = [i + 5, i + 15, j + 5, j + 15]
        
        m.add_gridlines(d=2.5, bounds=bounds, c=f"C{i%9}")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got the solution for it. I've edited the question to add the image to help users visualize the question better. Also with the image, I've added the code which worked for me.